# VBA - Evaluate(Replace(..)) get error with a particuliar input

Tags: excel, vba

There is a problem with evaluate(replace(..)) when I try to build a function in VBA. Please see the Excel file in link enlosed:

Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/eqsdqmmsyyoso93/Regression_PHAN.xlsm?dl=0

**Problem 01:** refering to UDF(User Defined Function)
The code for func01 is:

```
Function func01(str As String, X As Variant)
func01 = Evaluate(Replace(str, "x", X))
End Function
```

The problem is in cell A12. When I try using str input as "x" and particuliar input X = 1. This gives error while other values does not encounter any problem. Or using other function like "x^2" everything works fine. But not for "x" and X=1. I really have no idea where is the error

**Problem 02:** refering to Regression Toolbox
Scenario 01: If let everything by default or using any other function but "x". Everything works fine

Scenario 02: If we have one of 4 f(x) functions is "x" and the one of value of x is 1. Then the problem occur. This lead to msgbox "One of function of x, f(x), is invalid. Please check ..."

Scenario 03: If we have one of 4 f(x) function is "x" and non of x value is 1. Then the code run fine.

From 3 scenarios, the problem (as well as using debug mode) point to the code of problem 01: evaluate(replace(..))

For quick, you can search these lines:

```
For i = 1 To nr
    On Error GoTo Place01

    If str(1) = "" And str(2) = "" And str(3) = "" And str(4) = "" Then
        MsgBox "All field cannot be empty"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If str(1) <> "" Then Xc(1)(i, 1) = Evaluate(Replace(str(1), "x", X(i, 1)))
    If str(2) <> "" Then Xc(2)(i, 1) = Evaluate(Replace(str(2), "x", X(i, 1)))
    If str(3) <> "" Then Xc(3)(i, 1) = Evaluate(Replace(str(3), "x", X(i, 1)))
    If str(4) <> "" Then Xc(4)(i, 1) = Evaluate(Replace(str(4), "x", X(i, 1)))

    GoTo Place02

Place01:
    MsgBox "One of function of x, f(x), is invalid. Please check data again. Be careful with ln(x), 1/x, etc. since it cannot take negative or 0 value for those functions"
    Exit Sub

Place02:
Next i
On Error GoTo 0
```

I really have no idea why there is a problem with a particuliar "x" and input 1. While everything works fine for others

Thank you

Comment: How are you using `func01`? Like `=func01("x",1)`?

Comment: Yes, in Excel. For Cell A12 =func01("x",A1). Generally what this func01 doing is replacing a complicated function of x with x value. Let say I have function f(x) = x^2+ln(x). Then instead of entering in a cell formula as =Ln(A1) + A1^2, then I can simply go =func01("ln(x)+x^2",A1). the point is all function works fine except for when you enter =funct01("x",A1) and when A1=1. That when I have no idea how it get error

Comment: Piece of advice, get the error-handling subroutine out of the loop body - otherwise this code is in the early stages of serious spaghettification. You'll run into problems the day you need execution to continue instead of just msgbox+`Exit Sub`, because the error state is never reset. `GoTo Place02` has no business being there. Whenever you find yourself typing `GoTo` as anything other than an `On Error` statement, stop and re-think your control flow.

Comment: That said, `Evaluate(Replace(...))` is just a roundabout way to do invoke `WorksheetFunction.Replace`, ...which has a 100% VBA equivalent: `VBA.Strings.Replace`, or just `Replace` - there's no need to involve Excel's calc engine to replace a substring within a string.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon except that the OP is using the vba Replace to return a string that should be a formula that the `Evaluate` will resolve.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with `1` in `A1`, and using `=func01("x",A1)`.

Comment: @ScottCraner gosh, you're right.. and at this time I can't even blame lack of caffeine!

Comment: @ScottCraner: really? If you say you cannot produce any error then it is really sad cuz I have no idea what is going on worksheet :(. You can see picture capscreen here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/765zazuyre2jrxp/VBA%20Replace%2001.JPG?dl=0

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: sorry I dont get your point. So does this mean I need any modification to my code?

Comment: The `GoTo` jump doesn't need to be there, and the error-handling execution path shouldn't be intertwined with the logic like that; streamlining the control flow would make it easier to follow the different code paths IMO.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: Thank you. I am sorry if I could ask you to post lines of code need modification. That would help me a lot. I am learning VBA and I am not sure if I understand your explanation. Really sorry if this border you. Thank you

Comment: @BigBen: after checking around. The problem is more complicated than I thought. If you create a new worksheet and only add the function func01. Everything works fine. However, for some reason when adding UserForm. The problem occurs. I have to give up on this since I cannot understand how and why.

Answer (score 0):

After asking for several places. The solution for my problem is quite simple. Adding "=" after the Evaluate

The code should be:

```
Function func01(str As String, X As Variant)
func01 = Evaluate("=" & Replace(str, "x", X))
End Function
```

Everything is fixed nicely